# Upgrade file in TFS Source control

Tags: tfs

I need to upgrade some 3rd party library binaries in my project. So I want to remove SomeLibrary folder and then insert SomeLibrary with other content (or clear SomeLibrary content and then insert upgraded content).

Currently I have to make 2 check-ins for that: one for remove and one for add. If I remove and then try to add immediately I get an error telling this element already has pending changes.

Is there any way to do that by 1 check-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to change folders?

For example, if you have your binaries in e `lib` folder, simply check out the folder, overwrite the upgraded binaries, add any new ones, remove anything that's no longer needed, then check it all in at once.